# How to connect to a Websocket Server Hosted in Heroku with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, heroku, websocket

I have a Websocket server hosted in Heroku and my c# client script looks like this:

```
namespace csharp_client
{ 
    public class csharp_client : MonoBehaviour
    {
        WebSocket ws;

        private void Start()
        {
            ws = new WebSocket("wss://name.herokuapp.com/");
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Message recieved from:" + ((WebSocket)sender).Url + ",Data: "+e.Data);
            };
            ws.Connect();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (ws == null)
                return;
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))          
                ws.Send("Hello");          
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error in Unity saying that the connection is not open, this is my server code:

```
const Websocket = require('ws');

const portal=(process.env.PORT||5000);

const wsServer = new Websocket.Server({
    port: portal
})

wsServer.on('connection',function(socket){
    //Feedback
    console.log("a client just connected");
    //Behavior
    socket.on('message',function(msg){
        console.log("Recieved message from client: "+msg);
        //Reenviar
        socket.send("Resend message: "+msg);

        //Broadcast
        wsServer.clients.forEach(function(client){
            client.send("Reenviado a todos: "+msg);
        })
    })
})
```

I have my server.js init in terminal so I don't know what is the issue, I need to start something in Heroku? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried specifying the port `"wss://name.herokuapp.com:5000"` ? or whatever your port is .. and are you sure it's not a firewall thing? Can other apps /tools connect successfully?

Comment: Wow, my Unity project crashes with that